# How to increase mouse cursor speed in Ubuntu? (Gnome)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, gnome, speed

How do I increase the mouse speed in Ubuntu Linux? Running Gnome 2.30.0. I've already maxed out Pointer Speed Sensitivity in the Mouse Preferences control panel. I am not interested in increasing the Acceleration. Is there a config file I can edit to boost it past what the control panel allows?

I know that this mouse can track faster because it does in Windows.

Comment: What mouse do you have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, if I remember right you can use the command

> xset m X Y

With X and Y being two different values, Acceleration and Threshold I believe. These settings change after a reboot so you would have to add them into a startup script.
A quick search says that this command will give you your current value on ubuntu, but im not in a location I can try it right now.

> xset -q | grep accel

Also if you look in your Xorg.conf file under the section for mouse you should see an option title "Resolution" increasing this number should increase your mouse speed as well.

Comment: Why is it when anyone asks how to change mouse **speed** the reply always explains how to set **acceleration**?

Comment: I get `xset -q | grep accel
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4`

Not sure what values to set this to.

Comment: From the help page, but not very informative either: 
"To set mouse acceleration and threshold:
   `m [acc_mult[/acc_div] [thr]]    m default`"